# jsDevExpress : dxTextArea - How to get the text area value when onFocusOut?

Tags: angularjs

I am using jsDevExpress together with AngularJS, Is there a way to get the value of dxTextArea when user leave the widget? I know to do this using `onValueChanged: function (ovc) {}` but i am particularly interested the onFocusOut

```
$('<div/>').dxTextArea({
  value: "",
  height: 90,
  valueChangeEvent: "change",
  onFocusOut: function (ofo) {
        ?? ofo.value // not found
  }
```

The textarea is repeated per record inside in a column using dxDataGrid.